# Sed matches unwanted extra characters

Tags: regex, sed, cygwin

I want to replace parts of file paths in a configuration file using sed in Cygwin. The file paths are in form of `\\\\some\\constant\\path\\2018-03-20_2030.1\\Release\\base\\some_dll.dll` (yes, double backslashes in the file) and the beginning part containing date should be replaced.

For matching I've written following regex: `\\\\\\\\some\\\\constant\\\\path\\\\[0-9_\.-]*` with a character set supposed to match *only* date, consisting of digits and "-", "_" and "." symbols. This results into following command for replacement: `sed 's/\\\\\\\\some\\\\constant\\\\path\\\\[0-9_\.-]*/bla/g' file.txt`

The problem is that, after replacement, I get `blaRelease\\base\\some_dll.dll` instead of `bla\\Release\\base\\some_dll.dll` as it was successfully replaced using [Regexr](https://regexr.com/3mmht).

Why does sed behave this way and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the character class `[0-9_\.-]` is matching backslashes. If you replace the class with `[0-9_.-]`, it will do what you expect.

Note that in a character class, `.` isn't special and doesn't need quoting. For example, from my Cygwin command line:

```
$ echo '\.' | sed 's/[\.]/x/g'
xx
$ echo '\.' | sed 's/[.]/x/g'
\x
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple `sed` may help you on same.

```
sed 's/.*Release/bla\\\\Release/'    Input_file
```

In case you want to have backup of Input_file and save the output of it into Input_file itself then following may help you on same.

```
sed  -i.bak 's/.*Release/bla\\\\Release/'  Input_file
```

In another case if you simply want to save output into Input_file itself then following may help you on same too.(difference between above and this one is this one will not create a backup of original Input_file).

```
sed -i 's/.*Release/bla\\\\Release/'   Input_file
```